# How can I set source server on WinDBG preview?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

In Visual Studio 2015, I can set source server support on Options/Debugging/General.

But I don't know how to set source server on WinDBG Preview.

Comment: in options there is symbol and source path. Add server here and look if this works

Answer (score 0):

use the command .srcfix it will setup windbg to use the srcsrv.exe

quoting relevant part from debugger.chm

> .srcfix, .lsrcfix (Use Source Server) The .srcfix and .lsrcfix
>   commands automatically set the source path to indicate that a source
>   server will be used.
>
> .srcfix[+] [Paths]  .lsrcfix[+] [Paths]
>
> Parameters
>
> - Causes the existing source path to be preserved, and ; srv* to be appended to the end. If the + is not used, the existing source path is
>     replaced.
>
> Paths  Specifies one or more additional paths to append to the end of
>   the new source path.
>
> Environment The .srcfix command is available on all debuggers. The
>   .lsrcfix command is available only in WinDbg and cannot be used in
>   script files.